# Django datetime field (with sqlite database) returns unicode

Tags: python, django, sqlite, datetime

I'm writing a small Django app that displays a few simple values from an sqlite3 database. My problem is, although one of the fields is a DateTimeField, I get a unicode value for that field when querying. Here's the relevant part of the model:

```
class Totals(models.Model):
    time = models.DateTimeField(primary_key=True, blank=False)
    ..
```

Now if I for example type `Totals.objects.all()[0].time` in the Django shell (after importing Totals of course), I get `u'2012-01-03 04:02:56.966'`. Is this normal behavior perhaps, since I'm using sqlite, or is there something wrong? I'm not sure this is relevant, but I had the models auto-generated since I already had the database I wanted to use. The auto-generation procedure naturally had deducted all field types as text, so I fixed them accordingly.

Comment: Django db backends converts everything into unicode and sqlite3 always return unicode (UTF8 internal i believe)

Comment: But integer fields are converted properly. I'm aware of the fact that sqlite does not have a native datetime type, but since Django seems to be happy to parse integers for me and also since sqlite documentation recommends a standard date format that sqlite functions recognize, I thought perhaps Django would parse these values too. Others questions on stackoverflow (for example this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181145/why-isnt-django-returning-a-datetime-field-from-the-database) gave me that impression.

Comment: There's something wrong.. django should coerce the value to a datetime object or raise an error. Your model works when pasted into 1.3. Hmm?

Comment: I'm already using Django 1.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what is worth, I'm not getting that behaviour (I just get a `datetime.datetime` object back) using sqlite and I defined the model exactly in the same way you as you provided in the question.

My guess is that there was some problem during the auto-generation of the models and they don't really match the schema in the database. Hence, I'd recommend to verify that the schema that would be generated from those models actually matches.

In my case, what I see is as follows:

```
$ python manage.py sql <appname>
...
CREATE TABLE "<appname>_totals" (
"time" datetime NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
)
;


$ sqlite3 <database_filename>
.schema <app_name>_totals
CREATE TABLE "<app_name>_totals" (
"time" datetime NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);
```

Note: I'm also using Ubuntu 11.10 with python 2.7.2 and django 1.3.0

Comment: Yes, that's it. The column in the sqlite database was declared as text. As a matter of fact, I didn't know I could define columns as datetime in sqlite. Anyway, by changing the table schema, everything is fine now.

Comment: Thanks for posting this - this totally had me hung up as well.  In my case I was able to use SQLite Browser to set the column type to datetime, and Django was happy with that.